# Module unreachable using busted in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-busted

I'm a beginer with Lua and I would like to use unit tests in my devs.
I decided to use [busted](http://olivinelabs.com/busted) a simple and easy to use framework to do that.

```
require "yaci"
require "busted"

foo = {}
foor.bar = newclass( "foo.bar" )
function foo.bar:doSomething() return "foo bar" end

describe("Unit tests for Foo.Bar", function()

    it("A first test", function()

        local to_test = foo.bar()
        local text = to_test:doSomething()

        local a = { test = say }
        local b = { test = "foo bar" }
        assert.same( a, b )

    end)

end
```

But foo.bar looks to be unreachable...

```
attempt to index global 'foo' (a nil value)
```

Outside of `describe` theire is no problem.

Could someone explain me why foo.bar is unreachable in `describe` ?

Thanks

Comment: Unsure if this is a typo in your post or your code, but you have `foor.bar = newclass( "foo.bar")`

Comment: The instruction `foo.bar:doSomething = function() return "foo bar" end
` is also a syntax error. It can either be  `foo.bar.doSomething = function(self)...` or  `function foo.bar:doSomething()...` . So please check your code and correct the question.

Comment: I corrected my code and merged the two files.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the describe function sets the environment of the passed function to prevent it from interfering with other code files.